# How to mute sapply?

Tags: r, sapply

I want sapply to return nothing when condition gives no warning. How can I do this?

```
d <- data.frame(a = sample(x = 1:110, size = 20), 
                 b = sample(x = 1:110, size = 20))

sapply(d$a, function(x) if(x>110 | x<1) warning("bad numeros"))
```

Comment: For this example, I would argue that you simply shouldn't use `sapply`, instead something like `if(any(d$a >110 | d$a < 1)) warning("bad numeros")`

Comment: And if you want to test several/all columns, just use `if(any(d > 110 | d < 1)) warning("bad numbers detected")`.

Comment: @docendodiscimus   You should make your suggestion an answer.

Answer (score 2):

As commented, there's really no need for an `sapply` in this case. Just make a comparison on the whole vector and, if any bad numbers are found, give a warning.

For a single column, you can do it like this:

```
if(any(d$a >110 | d$a < 1)) warning("bad numbers detected")
```

And if you want to test all columns at the same time, you can simply use the whole data.frame in the comparison:

```
if(any(d > 110 | d < 1)) warning("bad numbers detected")
```

If you want to test several but not all columns in your data.frame, use the appropriate subset:

```
cols <- c("a", "b")
if(any(d[,cols] > 110 | d[,cols] < 1)) warning("bad numbers detected")
```